# Nodejs amqp buffer transfer

Tags: node.js, buffer, amqp

I have a front end webserver Node + Express that receives an uploaded file from a browser.  I then want to get the file data and send it via amqp to a worker.  This is my code for accepting the upload and sending the file over amqp :

```
    adminCommercialRegistration : function (req,res,next) {
    if(!this.checkLogin (req,res)) return;

        fs.readFile(req.files.html.path, function (err,data) {
            if(err)
            {
                res.json('Error reading uploaded file');
            }
            else
            {
                var metaData = {
                                companyName : req.body.companyName,
                                date : req.body.date
                               };
                var payLoad = { metaData : metaData, data : data };
                var connection = require('amqp').createConnection({ host : '172.27.164.28'});
                    connection.on('ready', function(){

                        console.log('Connected to ' + connection.serverProperties.product);

                        var exchange = connection.exchange('ooparoopa');
                        var queue = connection.queue('htmlFileUpload');

                        queue.on('queueDeclareOk', function(args) {
                            console.log('Queue Opened');
                            queue.bind(exchange, '#html');

                            queue.on('queueBindOk',function (){
                            console.log('Queue Bound');

                            exchange.publish('#html', { payLoad : payLoad });
                            res.redirect('/commercial');
                        });
                    });
                });                 
            }
        });
    },
```

This part works fine and will send the data.  I have inspected the data object on this side and it is a Buffer.

The code below is the worker process.  It receives the data and adds the required information to the database.  However, there is a problem with the file data.  It doesn't look like it is a buffer.  And I get the error message unknown encoding.  What must I do to get this back into a binary buffer?

```
connection.on('ready', function(){
console.log('Connected to ' + connection.serverProperties.product);

var exchange = connection.exchange('ooparoopa');
var queue = connection.queue('htmlFileUpload');

queue.on('queueDeclareOk', function(args){
    queue.bind(exchange, '#html');

    queue.subscribe({ack:true}, function (payLoad) {
        queue.shift();
        console.log('Message Received:');
        console.log(payLoad.payLoad.metaData.companyName);
        var Commercial = db.model('Commercial');
        var newCommercial = new Commercial({ companyName : payLoad.payLoad.metaData.companyName, date : payLoad.payLoad.metaData.date });
        newCommercial.save(function (err,newComm){
            if(err)
            {
                console.log(err);
            }
            else
            {

                console.log(payLoad.payLoad.data.length)
                var folder = '/var/www/ooparoopastatic/html/';
                var _id = newComm.id;
                var filename = _id + '.zip';

                console.log(payLoad.payLoad.data);
                fs.writeFileSync(folder + filename, buffer, function (err) {
                    if(err)
                    {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        console.log('Writing to file at:' + folder + filename);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
})
```

Comment: I achieved this by base64 encoding the .zip file and sending it over the message queue.  At the other end I base64 decode the string to a buffer and write this to disk.

I can't post the full answer to this as I don't have enough reputation I will later so that others may find it useful.

Comment: In the line `fs.writeFileSync(folder + filename, buffer, function (err) {` `buffer` isn't declared or set anywhere. Is the code you've shown actual, copy-and-pasted code, or did you retype it? Avoid retyping code, since oftentimes you'll inadvertently fix the problem in the process of retyping, so we'll see working code that differs from your non-working code.